# set sktexture to nil will help my game go faster?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, sprite-kit

I'm trying to optimize the code of my SpriteKit game doing the graphics and animations to draw images only if they are on the screen, what I want to do is to set the texture of the sprites that are not in the screen to nil and to stop their animations while I keep calculating their position, but I not sure if this is the best way to do that because i've read in apple documentation that it is not recomended to change an SKTexture in a loop which I don't really understand what that means or what the "loop" is. So I'm asking this question to know if this is the good way or if there is a better way to do that. I would really apreciate your help and thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting textures, even to the same texture, incurs some overhead. I don't know exactly what Sprite Kit does but it can add a noticable lag if you change textures dozens or hundreds of times per frame.

However, off-screen sprites are already culled and thus ignored by the renderer. Even if it weren't you could simply change the hidden property to prevent the sprite from being rendered.

Comment: He is a boss. @user3033437